# Doing subtraction on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, math

I have 3 column, and I'm trying to do some subtraction of two column on JavaScript. The first column's (column A) data are from the database, for the second column's (column B) data are user input, and the third column is for the value. I have successfully run the addition, but actually, what I want is subtraction. I have tried changing the sign + to - but turns out give me the wrong value. Can anyone help me?

this is my code

```
<tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $no; ?></td>

                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $data[$i]['nama_barang']?></td>

                        <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align:middle;" class="so"><?php echo $data[$i]['stock']; ?></td>

                        <td><input type="number" class="form-control so" id="stock_op" name="stock_op" style="text-align: left"></td>

                        <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align:middle; font-weight:bold;"><output class="result"></output></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php                                           
                    }
                ?>
    <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).on('input','.so',function(){
var grandSum = 0;
        var totalSum = 0;
        var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
        currentRow.find('.so').each(function(){
            var inputVal = ($(this).is('input')) ? $(this).val() : parseInt($(this).html());
            if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
                totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
            }
        });
        currentRow.find('.result').val(totalSum);
    });

    </script>

                </tr>
```

This is the table [image: UI]

Comment: You can get the values from database inside your javascript code and do whatever process on it like so `var phpValue = "<?php echo $data[$i]['nama_barang']?>";`

Comment: @AmrAly I don't get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are looping through both the stock/static number

```
<?php echo $data[$i]['stock']; ?>
```

ie `4`/`13`

and the user number

```
<input type="number" class="form-control so" id="stock_op" name="stock_op" style="text-align: left">
```

You need to still add the stock number and only subtract the user defined number.

So you can't do

```
totalSum -= parseFloat(inputVal);
```

as that will subtract both.

So you need to use `-$(this).val()` in

```
var inputVal = ($(this).is('input')) ? -$(this).val() : parseInt($(this).html());
```

as you want to subtract only the input field value.

See http://jsfiddle.net/gujex58p/

Comment: once more, what If I want Column B - Column A instead of Column A - Column B? put - sign on  `$(this).closest('tr');`?

Comment: No, you would use it on `-parseInt($(this).html());`, as that is the value from Column A.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add first value to total sum, and subtract second value as

```
if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
    if(totalSum==0)
            totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
     else
           totalSum -= parseFloat(inputVal);

        }
```

Comment: No, I just need the subtract, but if I change  `totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);` to `totalSum -= parseFloat(inputVal);` it gaves me wrong result.

Comment: Firstly you must have first row value in totalSum, omly then you can subtract second value from it, just try to run this code

Comment: If you are subtracting first row value from 0, then again subtracting second row value from result, how do you expect to get correct result, i hope you get it now